# Apache container cannot bind to well-known port despite holding capability CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE

Tags: systemd, containers

When attempting to run Apache inside a systemd container that was started with `systemd-nspawn --private-users=pick ...` (unlike `--private-users=false` in [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/888790/apache-wont-run-inside-container) solution) I encounter this error:

```
Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address ...:999
```

What puzzles me is that the container has been granted capability `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` (`getpcaps 1` inside the container also confirms this), `--capability=help` indicates that the capability is supported, and `netcat -l 999 -s ...` (also inside the container) can apparently listen on the same port just fine.

What am I missing? Shouldn't the capability allow processes inside the container to open well-known ports on the host, no matter what their PIDs are?

**UPDATE** I made a mistake with the invocation of `netcat`. The correct command line is `netcat -vl -p 999 -s ...` and this now produces "Can't grab ...:999 with bind : Permission denied". So in fact neither Apache nor netcat can bind at this point, and this is not Apache-specific. Two more facts about the configuration: container is running as `root` (mapped to non-root pid on host), `iptables` on host are empty.

**UPDATE** So perhaps capability `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` simply [cannot transcend user namespaces](https://lwn.net/Articles/528078/).

Comment: Wild guess: are you using SELinux or AppArmor? Also, do you get any more information in the logs? What is your configuration?

Comment: @Tommiie No there is no SELinux or AppArmor. The host runs Debian 10.

Comment: When I check a new install of the latest Debian, it has AppArmor enabled by default. Please share configurations.

Comment: @Tommie Thanks for the hint re AppArmor. I was not aware of this. So yes, `aa-status` says apparmor module is loaded. Not sharing other configurations right now, because there are so many aspects to "configuration".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come to the conclusion that capability `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` specifically and capabilities in general cannot transcend user namespaces. From `user_namespaces(7)`:

> User namespaces isolate security-related identifiers and attributes,
> in particular, user IDs and group IDs (see credentials(7)), the  root
> directory,  keys  (see  keyrings(7)),  and  capabilities  (see
> capabilities(7)).
>
> ...
>
> The  child  process  created  by  clone(2)  with the CLONE_NEWUSER
> flagstarts out with a complete set of capabilities in the  new  user
> namespace.  Likewise, a process that creates a new user namespace
> using unshare(2) or joins an existing user namespace  using  setns(2)
> gains a full  set  of  capabilities in that namespace.  On the other
> hand, that process has no capabilities in the parent (in the case of
> clone(2))  or previous  (in the case of unshare(2) and setns(2)) user
> namespace, even if the new namespace is created or joined by the  root
> user  (i.e., a process with user ID 0 in the root namespace).
>
> ...
>
> Having  a  capability inside a user namespace permits a process to
> perform operations (that require privilege) only on resources governed
> by that namespace.   In  other words, having a capability in a user
> namespace permits a process to perform privileged operations  on
> resources that  are  governed  by (nonuser)  namespaces associated
> with the user namespace (see the next  subsection).

From `network_namespaces(7)`:

> A  physical  network  device can live in exactly one network namespace.

Since my case involves a binding to the host's primary IP address the relevant physical network device must presumably be governed by the kernel's root network namespace. The capability `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` in my container's user namespace presumably has no bearing there since the root network namespace is not associated with that user namespace but with the kernel's root user namespace instead. So I am (presumably) out of luck here.

Comment: It sounds like this is the answer to your question so you can mark your own answer as the accepted solution.